# Rails: Change default format of the date_select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I change the default order of the date_select helper?

Answer (score 2):

**view**

```
date_select("set_date", "written_on", :order => [:year, :month])
```

**controller**

```
date = (params[:set_date])? params[:set_date] : DateTime.now
date = date.to_a.sort.collect{|c| c[1]}.join("-")
```

Answer (score 1):

The helper offers a [limited set of options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001698). If you want to apply further customizations, you need to create your own.

Comment: I was looking for a way to modify the default setting used by the date_select helper...so I don't have to make the change in every instance.